# how to use id to call the object in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

here is my html code

```
<p id="b1" onclick="clickFunction(this)" >+</p>
<p id="b2" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b3" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b4" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b5" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b6" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b7" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b8" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b9" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
```

here is my javascript code

```
var status = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
var gameStatus = {
    b1: 2,
    b2: 2,
    b3: 2,
    b4: 2,
    b5: 2,
    b6: 2,
    b7: 2,
    b8: 2,
    b9: 2
}

function clickFunction(element) {
    var ids = element.id
    document.write(gameStatus.ids) //but it returns undefined
};
```

Now I want to take the id and use that id to call the object in the gameStatus
gameStatus.id is giving me undefined.

I tried all the methods like converting it to number or string but nothing works.

Converting it to number give me Nan and converting it to sting and then using it gives me undefined. Please help me

Comment: Have a look at how [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) work

Comment: you can use gameStatus[element.id] to access the value of the corresponding property in the gameStatus  object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  another method of object.value call `obj[varible]`

In your method `obj.ids` ids refer to `keyname` of the object not the variable of `ids`

```js
var status=[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2];
var gameStatus={b1:2,b2:2,b3:2,b4:2,b5:2,b6:2,b7:2,b8:2,b9:2}
function clickFunction(element){
var ids = element.id
document.write(gameStatus[ids])//but it returns undefined
}
```

```html
<p id="b1" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b2" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b3" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b4" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b5" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b6" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b7" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b8" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
<p id="b9" onclick="clickFunction(this)">+</p>
```

Comment: There are about 500 duplicates of this issue!

Comment: 500 Duplicates?